# How to output the real and imaginary parts separately instead of having just one complex vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, complex-numbers

I have a function `M` that outputs complex numbers taking an input range of `r`'s. Instead of just outputting a single complex number, I would like to have the function to output two values (the real and imaginary parts separately) for all the output complex vectors. I would prefer the function to be anonymous function.

I tried the following but did not work since I am just getting single output complex values:

```
r = linspace(1E-10,1.5,100);
%M= (0.5*((1i*r+0.135).* (1i*r+0.651)))./((1i*r+0.0965).* (1i*r+0.4555))
M= @(r)(0.5*((1i*r+0.135).* (1i*r+0.651)))./((1i*r+0.0965).* (1i*r+0.4555))
```

How do I separate the real and complex parts of a vector?

Comment: I see you often do not ask a question, even though you filled out a box prompting you to "ask a question". Please do so, since the *question* part is what makes this post able to receive an *answer*, instead of merely an educated opinion. I have edited two of your posts to contain a proper question, please do this the next time when you ask a question; see [ask], contained in the help centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an anonymous function with a different variable to avoid confusion i.e. create `M` with:

```
M = @(k)(0.5*((1i*k+0.135).* (1i*k+0.651)))./((1i*k+0.0965).* (1i*k+0.4555));
```

then create another anonymous function, say `N`, that extracts [`real`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) and [`imag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imag.html) values and then stacks the result.

```
N = @(k) [real(M(k)); imag(M(k))];
```

Call this anonymous function with `N(r)` to get your expected result.

---

Alternately if you have already calculated `M` as in your commented out code then you can do:

```
N = @(k) [real(k); imag(k)];
```

and then call it with `N(M)`.